# Escape double quotes in a string when passing the string as input to client side from server side

Tags: javascript, c#

I have been trying to replace the double quotes in a string and tried many options and when trying to render the input to a textbox from server side it does not bind the value to textbox.

Below is the code snippet which I am using to bind the textbox from server side to client side :

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "RecreateDynamicTextboxes",
 "javascript:RecreateDynamicTextboxes('" + values.Replace("'", "&apos;").Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "');",
```

The above snippet trying to escape single and double quotes

When only trying to escape single quote the text binds to the textbox but does not work when trying to escape both single and double quotes in the string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that by *escape*, you mean *add a backslash (\) in front of the character to be escaped*:

```
string escapedValues = values.Replace("\"", "\\\"").Replace("'", "\\'");
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,
                                    GetType(),
                                    "RecreateDynamicTextboxes",
                                    "javascript:RecreateDynamicTextboxes('" + escapedValues + "');",
                                    // ...
```

With this, the following:

```
var s = "test";
var ss = 'test';
```

becomes:

```
var s = \"test\";
var ss = \'test\';
```

Comment: I analyized the html before rendering on the page and does look to me but does not show on the textbox .some where it is is reading just the value between " " and it will be always empty

Comment: This works finally .                          ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "RecreateDynamicTextboxes",
                    "javascript:RecreateDynamicTextboxes('" + values.Replace("\"", "&quot;").Replace("'", "&apos;") + "');",
                    true);